# Why is user: system doing an hourly backup of my SQL databases?

Tags: sql-server

I've got a pretty standard maintenance plan set up for my SQL Server databases; yet in addition to that plan, all of my databases, user and system, are backed up every hour by user: System... where is that getting initiated from and how can I turn it off?  There is also an associated MSMQ backup of components: registry, sysq, https, etc during the same time frame.

Comment: Check for a SQL maintenance plan, that is running hourly.  Check for a SQL Server Agent job.

Comment: Where/how are you seeing that it's being run by a user called "system"? Have you checked the backupset table in msdb for other relevant data (I've seen good stuff in name, description, software_vendor_id, etc).

Comment: When I see I/O frozen events I would start looking at software that tries to quiesce the system. Id start looking at either your storage appliance, if using Netapp then Snap Manager is most likely the culprit, VM Ware could be another.

Comment: Thanks Ben... Those backups were in the backupset table and through a little forensics with the dates in that table against the Windows Application event logs, I was able to determine that Dell AppAssure, installed by a user without me knowing, was responsible for those backups!  BTW... it's a very aggressive data management plan, does an hourly Differential backup on ALL databases...

Answer (score 4):

Your System Admin probably has a program such as BackupExec which backs up everything organisation-wide.  Check with them.

Typically, you'll see the backup device listed as a unique identifier, if some other system is managing backups.

I occasionally use this query to check backup history details:

```
DECLARE @DBName SYSNAME;
SET @DBName = DB_NAME(); -- modify these as you desire.
SET @DBName = NULL; -- comment this line if you want to limit the history
--SET @DBName = '<some database name>';
;WITH src AS 
(
SELECT DatabaseName = bs.database_name
    , BackupStartDate = bs.backup_start_date
    , CompressedBackupSizeMB = bs.compressed_backup_size / 1048576
    , ExpirationDate = bs.expiration_date
    , BackupSetName = bs.name
    , RecoveryModel = bs.recovery_model
    , ServerName = bs.server_name
    , BackupType = CASE bs.type 
          WHEN 'D' THEN 'Database' 
          WHEN 'L' THEN 'Log' 
          ELSE '[unknown]' END
    , LogicalDeviceName = bmf.logical_device_name
    , PhysicalDeviceName = bmf.physical_device_name
    , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bs.database_name 
            ORDER BY bs.backup_start_date DESC)
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset bs
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf 
        ON [bs].[media_set_id] = [bmf].[media_set_id]
WHERE (bs.database_name = @DBName
    OR @DBName IS NULL)
    AND bs.backup_finish_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
)
SELECT src.DatabaseName
    , src.BackupStartDate
    , CompressedBackupSizeMB = CONVERT(INT, src.CompressedBackupSizeMB)
    , src.ExpirationDate
    , src.BackupSetName
    , src.RecoveryModel
    , src.ServerName
    , src.BackupType
    , src.LogicalDeviceName
    , src.PhysicalDeviceName
FROM src
WHERE src.rn = 1
     AND src.DatabaseName NOT IN (
        'master'
        , 'model'
        , 'msdb'
        , 'tempdb'
     );
```

That should return a single row for each database backed up over the last 7 days.  You can limit this to a single database by modifying the `@DBName` variable.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, there are two possible areas for you to check (if you want to disable or change the hourly backup schedule)

Inside SQL Server, check sql agent jobs, for each Maintenance Plan, there is an corresponding sql agent job created, you can just modify the job (such as disable it or change its schedule)

Outside SQL Server, If the backup is done via 3rd party tool, the 3rd party tool may have its own schedule (i.e. not a sql job), you need to check with a system admin to find whether there is such tool.

But always first check sql server agent jobs to find whether there are hourly run jobs that may be the "culprits" for the backup.